# How to properly set and get using native storage ionic 4?

Tags: typescript, angular7, ionic4

I'm creating Ionic 4 plus Angular app, And I'm using Native Storage to 
save application data locally. below code I'm using but when I call get value it given null everytimes.

```js
this.storage.set('myValue', this.value);

this.storage.get('myValue').then(value => {
console.log('My value: ' + value);
})
```

result given My value:null

Comment: You mean you want to clear the cashe of browser ?

Comment: Whenever you set a value with a key, store all the keys in an array then loop through it and for each element call storage.remove(key)

Answer (score 1):

The main idea will be that we are going to store an array of all keys we used so we can loop through it and remove the data for each key

Let's assume the following example:

`firstService`

```
export clas FirstService {
   constructor(garbage: GarbageCollecterService){}

  // Let's assume here you are storing data in memroy
  storeDataInMemory(key1) {
    ...
    // At the end of the function store the key in an array , We need it later
    this.garbage.storeAllKeys(key);
   }
}
```

`secondService`

```
export clas SecondService {
   constructor(garbage: GarbageCollecterService){}
  storeDataInMemory(key2) {
    ...
    // At the end of the function store the key in an array , We need it later
    this.garbage.storeAllKeys(key);
   }
}
```

```
export class GarbageCollecterService {

   storeAllKeys(key) {
      let totalArray = [];
      // In case you have keys before
      storage.get('AllKeys').then(AllKeys => {
         totalArray = AllKeys
         totalArray.push(key);
      });

    }

   // The following function will take all keys out of memory and looping over them and foreach one will remove the data related to it
    clearAllData() {
     let totalArray = [];
     storage.get('AllKeys').then(AllKeys => {
      totalArray = AllKeys
      totalArray.foreach(ele => storage.remove(ele));
     });

    }
}
```

Now all you need to call `clearData()`,

Here the [Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage) documentation.

Comment: So you are not using the same Object of Storage for all services , i mean for all app, Create a different service which is only responsible to handle getting , setting and removing data from the same object

Comment: Are you using the same Storage object or for each service or page let's say you are creating a new one ?

Comment: Maybe you don't get the idea , 
Please feel free to create a single storage object across all your pages

Answer (score 0):

We need to remember that get and set are async calls.We need to get after the set has been completed.Within the callback of the set we need to call get,That is why we are getting stale values.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @gaus Make sure you’re waiting on storage.ready() before trying to interact with it. something like that

```
 this.storage.ready().then(() => {
      return this.storage.get('myValue');
    });
```

or you can use local storage instead of that